# How can I animate NSPopover size change?

Tags: swiftui, appkit, nspopover, nsviewrepresentable

I have a SwiftUI view with fields that changes according to an object type that is about to be created. Each type has a different amount of fields, what makes the popover size change. I would like to make that change in size animated. How can I do that? It’s not possible with SwiftUI, so I would need to use the NSViewRepresentable for the popover that will be shown when clicking SwiftUI buttons.